# Cycle through pages of search results and parse data

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am just trying to make Python look through all the web pages of a search results of a website:

```
remainder = "latter_part_of_url"

page = '?s=0'

urlstring = 'https://domain/search/' + str(page) + str(remainder)

pagenumber = str(page)+120

for i in range(120, 100000, 120):
    # I am trying to increment by 120, how do I do that?

print(urlstring)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wouldn't that be a simple:

```
    for new_page_num in range(int(page)+120, 100000, 120):
        urlstring = 'https://domain/search/' + str(new_page_num) + str(remainder)
```

I would use some string formatting rather than + though.

Comment: How does it know when to stop? What to use as a reference point for the code to stop operating when it sees the last page.

Comment: it stops when you reach 100000. Thats how the range(..) works.